# fitting a diagonal line to graph in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
> wider_data
# A tibble: 12 x 6
   treat    FR    CC    HP Other x    
   <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <fct>
 1 1         0     2     5     3 0    
 2 1         2     1     5     1 1    
 3 1         3     5     3     2 2    
 4 1         0     2     4     1 3    
 5 1         1     2     4     1 4    
 6 1         0     2     4     0 5    
 7 2         4     1     4     2 0    
 8 2         1     5     2     0 1    
 9 2         4     0     1     4 2    
10 2         0     5     2     3 3    
11 2         0     3     4     1 4    
12 2         1     5     1     2 5
```

I melt this data to

```
> m_wider_data <- melt(wider_data) #Using treat, levels, x as id variables
Using treat, x as id variables
> m_wider_data
   treat x variable value
1      1 0       FR     0
2      1 1       FR     2
3      1 2       FR     3
4      1 3       FR     0
5      1 4       FR     1
6      1 5       FR     0
7      2 0       FR     4
8      2 1       FR     1
9      2 2       FR     4
10     2 3       FR     0
11     2 4       FR     0
12     2 5       FR     1
13     1 0       CC     2
14     1 1       CC     1
15     1 2       CC     5
16     1 3       CC     2
```

(48 lines in total)

```
> class(m_wider_data$x)
[1] "factor"
> class(m_wider_data$value)
[1] "integer"
```

Then I plot 2 graphs (corresponding to the 2 levels of 'treat') using

```
plot_test <- m_wider_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = value, colour = variable, group = variable)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(treat), ncol = 2) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=variable)) +
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0) +
  labs(x = "X", y = "Y") +
  ggtitle('Table') +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) #turns of the legend title
```

However, the diagonal line ends up wrong

[image: graphs]

I want it to go through (0,0) (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) (4,4) (5,5).
In addition, I want cut the margins so that the graph area start so close to x=0 and y=0 as possible. I have tried to change x to a numeric variable and use

```
plot_test + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5),limits = c(-0.05, 5.05)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5),limits = c(-0.05, 5.05))
```

But it is not working.

Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

It's best to convert numeric. However, when converting a factor to a numeric you have to keep in mind that you first have to convert to a character. Otherwise your first category "0" becomes 1, your second category "1" becomes 2 and so on. Therefore always use `as.numeric(as.character(x))`.

After this change your code should work fine. Nonetheless I made some small changes. I set the limits via coord_cartesain. And also I used the expand argument to `scale_x/y_continuous` to set the default expansion (= 5 percent) to 0. BTW: You don't need to add an extra ".05" to you limits as ggplot will expand your axes by default. (If you are fine with the default expansion you ould simply remove `scale_x/y_continuous` or if you want a different expansion try e.g. `c(0.025, 0)` which will expand the axis by 2.5 percent on both sides.)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dpylr)

plot_test <- m_wider_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(as.character(x)), y = value, colour = variable, group = variable)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(treat), ncol = 2) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=variable)) +
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0) +
  labs(x = "X", y = "Y") +
  ggtitle('Table') +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,5), ylim = c(0,5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
plot_test
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
m_wider_data <- read.table(text = "treat x variable value
1      1 0       FR     0
2      1 1       FR     2
3      1 2       FR     3
4      1 3       FR     0
5      1 4       FR     1
6      1 5       FR     0
7      2 0       FR     4
8      2 1       FR     1
9      2 2       FR     4
10     2 3       FR     0
11     2 4       FR     0
12     2 5       FR     1
13     1 0       CC     2
14     1 1       CC     1
15     1 2       CC     5
16     1 3       CC     2", header = TRUE)

m_wider_data$x <- factor(m_wider_data$x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot as well! The graphs looks very nice now:)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is a result of x being a factor and not a number.  It is best to perform that conversion early in the process.
Also, I have updated the matrix transformation using the more modern `pivot_longer` instead of `melt`

```
widedf<-read.table(header = TRUE, text="   treat    FR    CC    HP Other x    
1         0     2     5     3 0    
1         2     1     5     1 1    
1         3     5     3     2 2    
1         0     2     4     1 3    
1         1     2     4     1 4    
1         0     2     4     0 5    
2         4     1     4     2 0    
2         1     5     2     0 1    
2         4     0     1     4 2    
2         0     5     2     3 3    
2         0     3     4     1 4    
2         1     5     1     2 5")


library(tidyr)
#make the table long
df <- pivot_longer(widedf, -c("treat", "x"), names_to="variable", values_to="value")
#convert x from a character to an integer
df$x <- as.integer(as.character(df$x))


library(ggplot2)
plot_test <- df %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = x, y = value, colour = variable, group = variable)) +
   facet_wrap(vars(treat), ncol = 2) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_line(aes(linetype=variable)) +
   geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0) +
   labs(x = "X", y = "Y") +
   ggtitle('Table') +
   theme(legend.title=element_blank()) #turns of the legend title
plot_test
```

Comment: @JMV, If this answered your question, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers